# How do I translate "Swipe your badge to sign in"

Tags: traducción

What is the Spanish Translation for "Swipe your badge to sign in"
This is what I have got,

> Deslice su tarjeta de identificación para iniciar sesión

Is the above correct ? Much appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks fine to me. There are other questions in this site related to [swipe](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=deslizar) but verb "deslizar" used as "deslice us tarjeta" is the one I would have chosen.

Comment: También creo que *pasar* sirve bien en este contexto.

Comment: @Diego I don't think this is a duplicate because the other question isn't about swiping cards — rather a finger on a screen. I think that's enough of a distinction to keep it open

Comment: @guifa, You should vote to reopen. I didn't VTC just because the question was very similar, but also because I thought some of the answers there already addressed what is being asked here. It is true that based on what we are swiping (and/or where) we may favor one verb over another ("pasar" vs. "deslizar") to describe the action. I'll maintain my VTC since, if I had to post an answer here I would post something very similar to what I posted in the other question, but I agree there might be room to keep both questions open, with more specific answers each.